# Redirect Azure WebPage Port to VM

Tags: java, azure, redirect, azure-web-app-service

I'm building a project that consists in one web site and one Java application. The web site is running as a Web App inside Azure, and my application is in a Virtual Machine in Azure too. This java application is a Web Server that an user could consume it from the internet.

So what i'm am trying to accomplish here is, when an user types `www.mysite.com`, it opens the web site, and when he types `www.mysite.com:8190/MyEPoint`, he should be redirected to my application in the virtual machine. So he can access my Web Server without using the IP directly.

Comment: Isn't this what HTTP 301/302 are for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my experience, there are two ways which can satify your needs, and it's not necessary to specify an alone port for a redirect request to VM.

1. As @DavidMakogon said, you can create a request filter in your Java Application to use the function like `response.sendRedirect()` to redirect a request for an url mapping pattern, that's based on `HTTP 30X`.
2. You can try to create an Azure Application Gateway for your website & VM to direct the request using URL pattern routing, please see the offical article [Create an application gateway using URL based routing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/application-gateway-create-url-route-arm-ps/) to know how to get started.